# Is it possible to detect when EventHandlers are added and disposed of outside of process?

Tags: c#, wpf

I think the answer is NO but I thought of asking to see if it's possible at all

Scenario: I have a WPF application that uses a `class` with `static` `event`s to subscribe interactions between different controls

Basically,

```
public class EventNotifier
{
    public static event EventHandler<SomeEventArgs> EventTriggered;
    public static void NotifyEventTriggered(object source, SomeEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (EventTriggered!= null)
        {
            EventTriggered(source, eventArgs);
        }
    }
}
```

Then from some controls some methods get subscribed:

```
EventNotifier.EventTriggered+= new EventHandler<SomeEventArgs>(SomeMethodToReceiveEvent);
```

And from some other controls the events are triggered:

```
EventNotifier.NotifyEventTriggered(null, eventArgs);
```

This is all very straightforward. When the controls that subscribed their methods are disposed the events are disposed as well:

```
EventNotifier.EventTriggered-= new EventHandler<SomeEventArgs>(SomeMethodToReceiveEvent);
```

Given the nature of WPF that makes memory leaks rife where events are not unsubscribed correctly, until now I've had to manually test every control every time a leak was happening to ensure events were being disposed correctly. This is very time consuming

Some tools that analyze memory usage that I've used are completely incompetent at identifying the event that wasn't unsubscribed that was causing a memory leak

This is why I've been dreaming of creating my own tool to detect every time a method is subscribed to an event and also detect every time it's unsubscribed

I know I could do it in code using properties like:

```
private static event EventHandler<SomeEventArgs> eventTriggered
public static event EventHandler<SomeEventArgs> EventTriggered
    {
        add
        {
            eventTriggered-= value;
            eventTriggered+= value;
            //Add code here to keep track somewhere of event
        }
        remove 
        { 
            eventTriggered-= value; 
            //Add code here to keep track somewhere of event
        }
    }
```

But my dream tool would be one that is external to my application and hooks up to a process to monitor its events. Am I just dreaming or is this possible in any way?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Is there any example on how to implement the last paragraph? (Implementing the Pattern for External Events)

Comment: Over a hundred posts at just SO for WeakEventManager, Google has another 28 thousand, 18 classes in the reference source.  Yes, there are examples.

Comment: I mean not just an example of WeakEventManager. An example of WeakEventManager using an "external code base" as mentioned in the last msdn paragraph. Or am I missing something?